# How to hook eclipse save on editor close action

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing plugin that needs to change edited file before it is saved. I've managed to successfull hook into file > save and file > save all by using IExecutionListener.

That does not work when document is saved in the result of save on editor close. How to hook this?

I tried using IResourceChangeListener but it is called after resource modification and this is too late.

Comment: For Eclipse 4 you could look at `ISaveHandler`. I'm not sure how you go about setting this up with 3.x compatibility code.

Comment: Doesn't editor part implements `IEditorPart` which in turn implements `ISaveablePart` ? The `ISaveablePart` has methods to implement such as `isSaveOnCloseNeeded()`, `doSaveAs()`

Comment: @svasa Thank you, but i am not implementing my own editor. Only a plugin which needs to detect closing of existing editors.